# Spring - Is not possible using @ModelAttribute without name when the parameter type is String?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

> I am developing web site using the spring-boot and thymeleaf.

On the url "/copy" I added an attribute named "type" to the model and forwarding "return test/form". I submit the "type" value from the form (at this time, send the "type" value to the server using input hidden element.) The server sends the error message to the frontend if a specific key value is already stored in the DB.
The important thing is that when I first call "/copy" and go to "/test/form", the html stores the type value well. But after forwarding, in the html the value of type as null.
Here's an example of the code below.

```java
public class TestController {
    // ... some codes
    @PostMapping("/copy")
    public String copyAndPaste(Model model) {
        try {
            model.addAttribute("myObj", myObj);
            model.addAttribute("type", COPY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "test/form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(
            @ModelAttribute @Valid MyObj myObj, // it works good.
            String type, // it doesn't work. 
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) throws Exception {

        if (!type.equals(EDIT) && checkCondition(myObj) {
            model.addAttribute("myObj", myObj);
            model.addAttribute("error", "An error occurred while registering.");
            return "test/form";
        }

        // some logics
    }
```

and test/form html file.

```html
<html>
 <body>
   ...html source
 <input type="hidden" name="type" th:value="${type}"/>
 <th:block layout:fragment="scripts">
   <script th:inline="javascript">
      var type = [[${type}]];
   </script>
 </th:block>
 </body>
</html>
```

in save method, the value of a parameter - String type -  is "COPY" (correct value). But in the if statement, in test/form the "type" is null value!!

So I changed my save method like this.

```java
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(
            @ModelAttribute @Valid MyObj myObj, // it works good.
            @ModelAttribute String type, // it doesn't work. 
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) throws Exception {

        if (!type.equals(EDIT) && checkCondition(myObj) {
            model.addAttribute("myObj", myObj);
            model.addAttribute("error", "An error occurred while registering.");
            return "test/form";
        }

        // some logics
    }
```

but not working, too.

Finally, I made this change.

```java
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(
            @ModelAttribute @Valid MyObj myObj, // it works good.
            @ModelAttribute("type") String type, // it works good. 
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) throws Exception {

        if (!type.equals(EDIT) && checkCondition(myObj) {
            model.addAttribute("myObj", myObj);
            model.addAttribute("error", "An error occurred while registering.");
            return "test/form";
        }

        // some logics
    }
```

Why not working this when I just attach @ModelAttribute or don't attach anything?

Why just working this when I attach @ModelAttribute with name (@ModelAttribute("type"))?

WHAT IS DIFFERENCE BETWEEN TWO?

Comment: ```BindingResult bindingResult``` has to follow the object that is bound. So I suggest you to move it to after ```@ModelAttribute @Valid MyObj myObj```. Let me know if it fix your problem

Comment: @tunapq It didnt fix my pb.. :(

Comment: It would be more correct to use `@RequestParam` for simple types rather than `@ModelObject`. i.e. `@ModelAttribute @Valid MyObj myObj, 
            @RequestParam String type`